# kbhit() in c same function in dart

Tags: c, dart, kbhit

I want to use kbhit() in c function in dart, but I don't find function in dart that work same kbhit().can you help me?

```dart
Stdin.echoMode = false;
Stdin.lineMode = false;

Stdin.readByteSync();
```

I tried with this code create a function that worked same kbhit(), but when use that function terminal blocked. I don't want to terminal blocked until press a key like kbhit() function.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. The `kbhit()` extension in C does not block, it just reports, and it isn't a `stdin` function: those functions are typically blocking and line-oriented too.

Comment: read how to listen to keyboard events in dart

Comment: You perhaps want something like [`package:console`](https://pub.dev/packages/console) or a package that provides ncurses support.